# Handling immutable borrow inside of closure that is part of a mutable borrow

Tags: rust

As part of the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html), I implemented a `Cacher` struct with generics. `Cacher` contains two fields: a closure `calculation` and a `value` field which is a `HashMap`:

```
use std::{collections::HashMap, hash::Hash};

struct Cacher<T, U, V>
where
    T: Fn(U) -> V,
    U: Eq + Hash,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: HashMap<U, V>,
}

impl<T, U, V> Cacher<T, U, V>
where
    T: Fn(U) -> V,
    U: Eq + Hash,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T, U, V> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            value: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> &V {
        self.value
            .entry(arg)
            .or_insert_with(|| (self.calculation)(arg))
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with the `Cacher::value` method which should do the following:

- If the `value` `HashMap` contains a key matching the provided argument, then return the corresponding value.
- If the `value` `HashMap` does not contain a key matching the argument, execute `Cacher`'s `calculation` closure. Save the result of this closure in the `HashMap`, using the provided argument as the key.

I've tried a variety of solutions that always result in conflicts between mutable borrows and immutable borrows. I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:27:29
   |
24 |       fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> &V {
   |                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
25 |           self.value
   |           ----------
   |           |
   |  _________mutable borrow occurs here
   | |
26 | |             .entry(arg)
27 | |             .or_insert_with(|| (self.calculation)(arg))
   | |_____________________________^^__----__________________- returning this value requires that `self.value` is borrowed for `'1`
   |                               |   |
   |                               |   second borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
   |                               immutable borrow occurs here

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `arg`
  --> src/lib.rs:27:29
   |
12 | impl<T, U, V> Cacher<T, U, V>
   |         - consider adding a `Copy` constraint to this type argument
...
24 |     fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> &V {
   |                         --- move occurs because `arg` has type `U`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
25 |         self.value
26 |             .entry(arg)
   |                    --- value moved here
27 |             .or_insert_with(|| (self.calculation)(arg))
   |                             ^^                    --- use occurs due to use in closure
   |                             |
   |                             value used here after move
```

I'm running into a compile-time error because `self.value.entry().or_insert_with()` is a mutable borrow, while the use of `self` in the closure inside of `or_insert_with()` triggers an immutable borrow.

I'm also running into an error in the value method because I'm passing ownership of `arg` into `entry()` and trying to use it again inside of the closure. Should I be using references in this method? If so, how?

I understand the issues from a high level, but I'm struggling trying to find a fix around it. What can I do to prevent a mix of mutable and immutable borrows when trying to read or write to the `value` `HashMap`?

**Solution**

The [solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54ea24f045d40a6b41d5830a8e4d5e82) I settled on.

The closure signature changed to `Fn(&U) -> V` and the `value` method changed to:

```
fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> &V {
    match self.value.entry(arg) {
        Entry::Occupied(e) => e.into_mut(),
        Entry::Vacant(e) => {
            let v = (self.calculation)(e.key());
            e.insert(v)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your error? It may be because of your compiler version, but when I compile your code, the error is not a borrow conflict - it's instead because you pass `arg` as an owned value into `entry`, and then try to reuse it in the closure of `or_insert_with`. In fact, there's no way to do what you want with your current types - inserting the key requires ownership of the key, and the calculation requires ownership of the key.

Comment: I see both the error you mentioned and the error mentioned in my post.  Should I be utilizing a reference to the arg param in the value method, rather than have the value method take ownership of "arg"?

Comment: You can't do that - the call to `entry` takes ownership of the argument, so you can't reference it afterwards. If you try to get the reference from the entry using `Entry::key`, you'll have a borrow which will stop you from using `Entry::or_insert_with`, since that requires ownership.

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54ea24f045d40a6b41d5830a8e4d5e82) (and yes, I'd use a reference)

Comment: I apologize that it's a duplicate question - I wasn't quite sure how to phrase it, so I wasn't sure where I could find that it was already answered. Thank you for taking the time to answer the question @Shepmaster!

Comment: @PramodJacob no need to apologize for duplicates. Now that you’ve asked yours, anyone who uses the same terms will find this and be redirected to the original questions.